# Store array in a JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to display the values of an array in a JTable column using a for loop.

My code looks like this:

```
public class MigTable extends FormsTableModel implements XmlInterface {

    private Element srcDoc = null;
    private String string = null;
    private ArrayList<Integer>data =new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(20,10,100));

    public MigTable(Element element, String string) {
        super(element,string);

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex){
            case 0: return  super.getColumnClass(0);
            case 1: return super.getColumnClass(1);
            case 2: return Integer.class;
            default: return Object.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex){
            case 0: return super.getColumnName(0);
            case 1: return super.getColumnName(1);
            case 2: return "status";
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            // Here I'm getting the values 
            if (columnIndex==2){
                // I would like to do it here so that at column Index 2 has the datas
                //from the array list 20 10 100
            }
        }
        return super.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i2) {
        // TODO Implement this method
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex > getColumnName(columnIndex).length())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("" + rowIndex);
        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps you could fix your indentation if you are asking people to try and read your code.

Comment: Sorry Khelwood come again! i didnt get what you meant? what would you like to understand on my Code ! give me an example  and i will correct the rest

Comment: What is your inheritance chain? Does `FormsTableModel` extend `DefaultTableModel` or `AbstractTableModel`, for example?

Comment: Format ugly code. It's like people don't give a hell about the people reading their crap and want help.
Removed unrelated tags

Comment: Sorry people it´s was my first post on task overflow ! my problem was solved i will care more about it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // here i am getting values 
    if (columnIndex==2){
        // i would like to do it here so that at column Index 2 has the datas from the array list 20 10 100 }
        if (rowIndex < data.size()) {
            return data.get(rowIndex);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return super.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
```

(I have not tested)

EDIT: The other option, granted that your superclass can handle it, putting the data there. `DefaultTableModel` can, for example. Put a few lines extra in your constructor:

```
public MigTable(Element element, String string) {
    super(element,string);
    for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++) {
        setValueAt(data.get(index), index, 2);
    }
}
```

With this you need not override `getValueAt()` at all.

Comment: thx for your reply ! but not Exactly ! i have a JTable with 3 Columns and 3 Rows  ! i alredeay have the datas for column 1 and 2 !now  at column 3 (columnindex 2) i would like to put the values of an Array in That.  The array is declare as int [] array = new int []{100, 30, 60};

Comment: I don’t understand the difference between what you want and what I give you. The data for the first two columns, are they in the superclass so `super.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)` will get them?

Comment: thx i didnt read your Answer very well ! :) It´s working for me now.